# Why this is not working scrollIntoView? What I do wrong?

Tags: javascript

Why this not work? What's wrong?

What I am do wrong?

```
window.onload=function()
{
    document.getElementById('bbb').scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m21v8rLu/)

When I press button, div scrolls must go down and show me a 'bbb' element.
Thanks.

Comment: Show your HTML as well.

Comment: Works fine for me, make sure your HTML is correct. It should contain something like this: `<span id="bbb">Foo</span>`. Please edit your question and try to add some more information.

Comment: I updated your example, and it works - http://jsfiddle.net/qvrLvdqp/ jsFiddle will automatically execute the JS on load, therefore you needed to change the option at the top left to "No wrap - in <head>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the problem in jsfiddle - you've set the script to get parsed onLoad, and at that point the window.onload has already fired, so nothing happens.

When you change the script load to be embedded in `head`, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/m21v8rLu/4/